# How to return arraobject if the particular property exists in nested array object using javascript;

Tags: javascript

How to check the particular property exists in nested array object using javascript;

In the below `arrobj`, if `value` property is empty, remove and return the array of object

If all object property value is empty, return [];

using javascript.

```
var arrobj = [
  {
    id: 1,
    task: [
      {tid:1, value:[]},
      {tid:2, value:[12,13]}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    task: [
      {tid:4, value:[14,15]}
    ]
  }
]
```

```
Tried

var valueExists = arrobj.filter(e=>e.tasks.filter(i =>i.value.length > 0);
```

Expected Output:

```
 [
  {
    id: 1,
    task: [
      {tid:2, value:[12,13]}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    task: [
      {tid:4, value:[14,15]}
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the array, generate a new object for each enter. Filter the tasks and remove all tasks that have a length of 0. After mapping, filter it and remove all objects with empty `task` array:

```js
const filterTasks = arr => arr
  .map(o => ({
    ...o,
    task: o.task.filter(t => t.value.length)
  }))
  .filter(o => o.task.length)


const arr1 = [{"id":1,"task":[{"tid":1,"value":[]},{"tid":2,"value":[12,13]}]},{"id":2,"task":[{"tid":4,"value":[14,15]}]},{"id":3,"task":[{"tid":5,"value":[]}]}]
const arr2 = [ {"id":1,"task":[{"tid":1,"value":[]},{"tid":2,"value":[]}]}, {"id":2,"task":[{"tid":4,"value":[]}]}]

console.log(filterTasks(arr1))
console.log(filterTasks(arr2))
```

Comment: Dori thanks, but if all task property value empty, then should return [], this scenario fails

Comment: No it doesn't. I've added another object with `id: 3` to the example `{"id":3,"task":[{"tid":5,"value":[]}]}`.

Comment: Ur exxample works, considering this example `const arrobj = [
{"id":1,"task":[{"tid":1,"value":[]},
{"tid":2,"value":[]}]},
{"id":2,"task":[{"tid":4,"value":[]}]
}
]
`, for this should return [] since all task property value seems to be []

Comment: This is not clear from your question. Update it with this case as well.